# Group and count dates matching only the day excluding time in mongoDB using mongoose

Tags: mongodb, date, mongoose

I have a document `links` like this

```
{
    "_id": "60043f2e10a0f677742b3997",
    "visit_count": 1,
    "password": null,
    "password_protected": false,
    "description": null,
    "analytics": [
        "60043fd7443aee6a585ca0d6",
        "60043563a6b1d440183a1b63"
    ],
    "alias": "m218",
    "short_url": "https://reduced.me/m218",
    "long_url": "https://test.com",
    "created_at": "2021-01-17T13:44:14.887Z",
    "updated_at": "2021-01-17T13:47:03.814Z",
    "__v": 1
}
```

and another document `analytics` like this

```
{
    "_id": "60043fd7443aee6a585ca0d6",
    "os": {
        "windows": true,
        "linux": false,
        "mac": false,
        "android": false
    },
    "browser": {
        "opera": false,
        "ie": false,
        "edge": false,
        "safari": false,
        "firefox": true,
        "chrome": false
    },
    "details": {
        "os": "Windows 10.0",
        "browser": "Firefox",
        "version": "84.0",
        "platform": "Microsoft Windows",
        "source": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"
    },
    "visit_date": "2021-01-17T13:47:03.796Z"
    "__v": 0
},

{
    "_id": "60043563a6b1d440183a1b63",
    "os": {
        "windows": true,
        "linux": false,
        "mac": false,
        "android": false
    },
    "browser": {
        "opera": false,
        "ie": false,
        "edge": true,
        "safari": false,
        "firefox": false,
        "chrome": false
    },
    "details": {
        "os": "Windows 10.0",
        "browser": "Edge",
        "version": "87.0.664.75",
        "platform": "Microsoft Windows",
        "source": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.141 Safari/537.36 Edg/87.0.664.75"
    },
     "visit_date": "2021-01-17T13:02:27.663Z",
    "__v": 0
}
```

I'm populating the `analytics` array in `links` document from the `analytics` document. what i want to achieve is to get an object of the `visit_date` field from each `analytics` document and count the number of all dates matching them only by the `day-month-year`, i don't want to match the time.

so the final output i am looking for is something like this

```
{
    //rest of the document fields

"visit_date": {
    "2021-01-17":2
      //and so on dates
    }

}
```

here `"2021-01-17":2` is from the two `analytics` document and only the `d-m-y` values in date are matched. where `2` is the number of matched dates and `2021-01-17` is the matched date

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [lookup with pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries),

- `$lookup` with analytics, pass analytics id to `let`
- `$match` analytics id condition
- `$group` by `visit_date`, `$substr` to get date from visit_date
- `$project` to show required fields and make, k(key) and v(value) format
- `$addFields`, convert `visit_date` array to object using `$arrayToObject`

```
db.links.aggregate([
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "analytics",
      let: { analytics: "$analytics" },
      pipeline: [
        { $match: { $expr: { $in: ["$_id", "$$analytics"] } } },
        {
          $group: {
            _id: { $substr: ["$visit_date", 0, 10] },
            v: { $sum: 1 }
          }
        },
        {
          $project: {
            _id: 0,
            k: "$_id",
            v: 1
          }
        }
      ],
      as: "visit_date"
    }
  },
  { $addFields: { visit_date: { $arrayToObject: "$visit_date" } } }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/dhxvz1-Pnr9)

Comment: this works for the given case, but it does not show the the count for other dates. i added one more object to `analytics` with date `"2021-01-18"` but this soln still only shows "2021-01-17": 2

Comment: make sure that `_id` should available in analytics collection, see i have added new document for `2021-01-18` in this [playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eTa1wNOFM2t)